# Documenting HttpServletRequest with Swagger

Tags: java, rest, resteasy, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a REST endpoint that is used to POST data. So far, I've documented in using swagger as below.

```
@POST
@OPTIONS
@Path("{serviceVersion}/{dataType}")
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@ApiOperation(value = "Post to Application", 
notes = "End Point to post Data")
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error (NON-retryable)") })
public String postData(@Context HttpServletRequest req,
        @Context HttpServletResponse resp,
        @ApiParam(value = "Service Version. Ex: v1", required = true, defaultValue="v1") @PathParam("serviceVersion")String serviceVersion,
        @ApiParam(value = "Topic Name", required = true, defaultValue="topic") @PathParam("dataType")String dataType,
        @ApiParam(value = "Delivery Mode", required = false) @QueryParam("deliveryMode")@DefaultValue("persistent") String deliveryMode,
        @Context UriInfo uriInfo);
```

How can I document `@Context HttpServletRequest req`? I need this because I want to let user's submit data from swagger-UI.

PS: The way data is actually read from the request is `request.getReader();` or `request.getInputStream();`

Comment: It's not clear why you need HttpServletResponse here. Can you expand on that please?

Comment: @Ron `HttpServletResponse` and `HttpServletResponse` are required in the implementation of the method.

Comment: But what do you expect to document here? What do you actually read from the request that's provided by the user?

Comment: @Ron The purpose of the method is to allow users to post JSON/Text files to the server.

Comment: The reason I ask for the the way to document is because I want the user's to test the API using swagger-UI and for that they need to post with request body.

Comment: You don't need to do that in order to process a request body. A parameter with no @XXXParam annotation is considered a body parameter. That's supported in any JAX-RS framework, and swagger-core processes it automatically as a body parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74964/discussion-between-vaishak-suresh-and-ron).

Comment: @Ron Thanks for the help so far.
I understand that the request would be available, but how can I let the user's create teh request body?
a file upload in this case.

When I test with curl, this is how I do it. 
`curl -X POST-d@JSONFile.txt http://<server>:8080/<app>/v1/smoketest`

Comment: @VaishakSuresh Did you find any solution to your problem ?I am facing similar situation where in user need to copy the content of the file (it can be any type) to the body